# Ocaml type error

Tags: types, int, ocaml

I'm learning OCaml, and this is my first typed language, so try to be patient with me:

For practice, I'm trying to define a function "divides?" which inputs two ints and outputs a boolean describing whether 'int a' divides evenly into 'int b'. In my first attempt, I wrote something like this:

```
let divides? a b =
if a mod b = 0 then true
else false;;
```

which gave the type error:

```
if a mod b = 0 then true
  ^
Error: This expression has type 'a option
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

So then I tried to turn it around and I did this:

```
let divides? a b =
 match a mod b with
  0 -> true
 |x -> false;;
```

which didn't help much: 
   `Characters 26-27
       match a mod b with
             ^
    Error: This expression has type 'a option
           but an expression was expected of type int`

Then I tried this:

```
let divides? (a : int) (b : int) =
 match a mod b with
 0 -> true
|x -> false;;
```

which elicited this:
          Characters 14-15:
         let divides? (a : int) (b : int) =
                      ^
     Error: This pattern matches values of type int
            but a pattern was expected which matches values of type 'a option.

I'm very confused and frustrated regarding the type system in general right now. (My first language was Scheme, this is my second.) Any help explaining where I'm going wrong and suggestions on how to fix it is much appreciated.

Comment: (As in most languages, you can replace `if <expr> then true else false` with just `<expr>`.  Just something to keep in mind.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that you can't use the question mark character <kbd>?</kbd> in a variable/function name in OCaml. It's actually parsing your function declaration like this:

```
let divides ?a b =
   if a mod b = 0 then true
   else false
```

Note that the question mark is actually affecting the type of `a`, rather than being part of the name of the function.

This means `a` is an [optional parameter](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual006.html#htoc38), so it gets assigned the type `'a option` for some `'a`.

Try removing the question mark from the name.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was going crazy, checking textbooks, browsing every site on the Internet for an answer... Thank you.

Comment: No problems, glad we could help!